# gwt compile need lot of heap memory

Tags: java, gwt, memory-management, uibinder

In order to gwt compile permutation, i need to use -Xmx1824m -XX:+UseParallelGC or else, i will get error out of heap memory.  what is the optimum extra java parameters that you folks use for

```
case 1:faster compilation 
case 2:lesser consume memory but slower compilation?
```

can share your jvm parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a relatively large GWT application code base (few 100K lines) which we compile with i18n (extra permutation per language per browser permutation). Running it with `-Xmx1024m` is fine. What you might want to do is boost your `PermGen` size. That is what get's used when GWT compiles the Java into Javascript. You can do this by adding `-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m`.

Also, if you want faster compile, you can tell GWT to compile more than one permutation at a time. Usually you set this to the number of cores on your processer + 1. So, on a Core2 Duo, you would set the number to 3. You can do this by setting the `GWTC.WORKERS` property in your `build.xml` if you are using `ant`.